# Laravel image gallery logic

Tags: php, image, image-processing, laravel

I recently started to develop a pretty huge site.
On the site i would like to allow users to upload their sample works.
We are pretty limited at the moment so the images will be stored on our server.

I am a bit stuck with the logic.
So my logic would be this.

User creates a folder with a name that is stored in the database with the `users id` attached to it

**folder table**

**Rows**

```
id | folder        | user_id 
1  | Some folder   | 1
2  | New folder    | 4
3  | Nother folder | 7
```

**Images table**

**Rows**

```
id | image_name        | folder_id |
1  | image1.jpg        | 1
2  | image2.jpg        | 1
3  | image3.jpg        | 1
4  | image4.jpg        | 2
5  | image5.jpg        | 2
6  | image6.jpg        | 2
```

Relations

```
class Folder extends Eloquent 
{
    public function images()
    {
        return static::has_many('Images');
    }
}

class Image extends Eloquent 
{
    public function folder()
    {
        return static::belongs_to('Folder');
    }
}
```

folder structure on server

```
- samples
  -user_id
   - folder_id
     - image1
     - image2
     - image3
```

so as you can see, user creates a folder, after the folder is created, `user` uploades the image name in to the database with the `folders id`, and showing the images would be the way describe above with the realation.

So my questions.

- Is this a good logic in your opinion
- can this lead problems in the future
- what woud you offer for this functionality

And what i am most sacred of are 2 things.

I think this will lead to a huge database, second are the `id's`, after x time when there will be more users, the `id's` will increase, and i know this will sound strange, but since lot of users will upload images will lead to huge id's, what i mean by this it will maybe reach millions, is there a way to solve this problem?

Thank you for the help

Comment: I have the same tables but I want any login user can view all the images of other users but can update(edit) and delete only his/her its own.Kindly guide me if any one has the solution.I am stuck over here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Ok - lets break this down into a few sub-answers;

**Question:**

```
- Is this a good logic in your opinion
- Can this lead problems in the future
- What would you offer for this functionality
```

**Answer:**

The logic seems sounds - but I'm curious *where* you will store the images? Inside public_html - or outside the web root? If you have the images inside public_html - and allow the browser to access them directly, it will allow users to 'guess' other user folders and access those. You need to store the data securely.

To make images outside the webroot, and make sure only authorized users can access them - you should use [readfile()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php). Something like this will do the trick

```
function user_file($file_name = "")
{
    if ($file_name)
    {
         // Ensure no funny business names to prevent directory transversal etc.
         $file_name = str_replace ('..', '', $file_name);
         $file_name = str_replace ('/', '', $file_name);

         // now do the logic to check user is logged in
         if (Auth::check())
         {
                // Serve file via readfile() - we hard code the user_ID - so they
                // can only get to their own images
               readfile('../your_app/samples/'.Auth::user()->id.'/'.$file);
         }
    }
}
```

**Question:**

> I think this will lead to a huge database, second are the id's, after x time when there will be more users, the id's will increase, and i know this will sound strange, but since lot of users will upload images will lead to huge id's, what i mean by this it will maybe reach millions

**Answer:**

According to the [mySQL features page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/features.html):

> We use MySQL Server with databases that contain 50 million records. We also know of users who use MySQL Server with 200,000 tables and about 5,000,000,000 rows.

So thats 5 billion rows. You will maybe get to a few million. So you are safe here (depending upon your hardware).

**Question:**

> ...but since lot of users will upload images will lead to huge id's,
>   what i mean by this it will maybe reach millions, is there a way to
>   solve this problem?

**Answer:**

If you dont want to store millions of records, and your worried about performance, one option is to keep the folder table, but drop the image table. Instead you can use [scandir()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.scandir.php) on the folder - and get PHP to retrieve the file names from the directory itself. Then you dont have as much overhead.

```
<?php
    $list_of_user_files = scandir("$user_id/$folder_id");
    foreach ($list_of_user_files as $file) {
          echo "File: $file <br>";
    }
?>
```

Comment: thank you for the detailed answer, the images will be stored in the storage folder, and yes i know, protection for that is taken care of :)

Answer (score 1):

The metode of Storing the folder table and using the scandir function is a standared procedure. And allow php to retrive the file names from the folder. If you have a number of files then try categorizing them with year and month order like in wordpress.
Like

```
2012
  01
  02
  03
2013
  01
  02
  03
```

etc inside the folder id. So the total number of images in a folder will be comparatively less.