# REST API and images

Tags: php, angularjs, image, rest, laravel

We are creating website using Laravel 5.2 (REST API) and AngularJS.

Everything was going well until "Image Gallery", which is created from files stored on the server.

At first I found some information here:
[Laravel image gallery logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14704998/laravel-image-gallery-logic). They didnt use REST API but it was good point to start.

Then I found some information about storing images in public folder and sending through API path to them like: "public/images/folder1/image.jpg", but as some other people points out this is not secure. It will be very easy to "guess" what other paths to images can looks like. Sure I can always create some unique guid for every image and store it in database, but I dont know if this is the best way to go. I dont like the general idea of storing all user personal informations (images) in folder "public".

Then I have found another piece of information here: https://www.codetutorial.io/laravel-5-file-upload-storage-download/ where author wrote how to actual send image data using REST API, but there is a catch. GET request is downloading only one file, so if I have 20 images on single page, then I have to send 20 GET requests to the server to get them (imagine 100 users). Again, I dont think this is the best way to solve my problem.

Probably I would prefer to send all images in single request, but is this good idea? Create one big JSON and split?

Can someone help me or at least give some fresh idea how to deal with it? I think I missed something important here.

Comment: Do the UUID approach. That's what most major sites do - take a look at the URLs in Twitter, Facebook, Google, etc.'s images. You really don't want to store image data directly in a database, and you really don't want to involve the PHP in a bunch of static file requests.

Comment: I didnt store them directly in a database but in folders on server. I was just wondering what is better: "send all file or just path to it" through API. But thank you for your help I will do my resarch on UUID.

Answer (score 0):

UUID ( universally unique identifier ) will help you solve this issue store and fetch on this, minimizes hacks and other attacks also secure your public folder .htaccess file as per your current secure requirement.